# Magento 1.9.1.0 Order email stopped working after the latest security patch instalation

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, patches, order-email

Magento order confirmation email was working properly, suddenly it stopped working after the installation of latest magento security patch. I am also  unable to preview the new order template.

**Error trace**

```
2015-07-14T14:05:02+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Missing To header' in /home/shop_production/htdocs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:183
Stack trace:
#0 /home/shop_production/htdocs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(337): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_prepareHeaders(Array)
#1 /home/shop_production/htdocs/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(241): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#4 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(79): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#8 /home/shop_production/htdocs/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#9 {main}
```

Comment: Please update the question with the patch number that you have installed.

Comment: Issue seems to be related with Aoe_Scheduler, have you tried disabling it?

Comment: @ Anshu Mishra patch I updated was PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh. Upon  clear examination I found that after applying the patch also, order email worked. But I didn't do any code change after the patch.

Comment: @mbalparda I have tried disabling the Aoe_Scheduler also but no luck.

Comment: /htdocs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php   function :   protected function _prepareHeaders($headers). I logged the $header in the log [To] array is missing.  message [From] => Array
        (
            [0] => gridzDIRECT Sales <sales@gridzdirect.com>
            [append] => 1
        )

    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue, 14 Jul 2015 19:30:02 +0000
        )

    [Content-Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html; charset=utf-8
        )

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually?